# How to Create a WordPress Laravel-Based Plugin

Tags: wordpress, laravel-5

I need to create a WordPress plugin. This plugin is actually a Laravel project. Why I would do that? because we are making a mobile eCommerce application and we have already a WordPress website for the company we are creating the mobile application for, so we need to plug-in the WooCommerce to the WordPress website then exposing some REST APIs to the mobile application (i.e., getting products on sale, placing orders, creating a new customer etc.). In case anyone answer will be that WooCommerce having its own REST APIs, unfortunately it won't work as it requires oAuth 1.0a as its authentication method when requests comes from a remote client, not the same machine, and the mobile app will be created using Ionic 4 and Angular 5/6 and they do not support oAuth 1.0a.

I tried to create a WordPress plugin using the standard way by downloading the laravel project at the WordPress plugins folder and I created a plugin file within the laravel root directory and within it I referenced the **server.php** file in the same directory which is responsible for initiating the composer auto-loader and then bootstrapping the laravel, however, it did not work for me!!! I also tried a package [laraish](https://packagist.org/packages/laraish/laraish)
However, when I created a simple hello world route it does not respond!

Comment: if you want to create an ecommerce app then just create API for everything, create, login, get the product by id or whatever you want to display in the app.

Comment: OK that is what I want but it needs to create the laravel project as WordPress plugin to get access to WordPress and WooCommerce functions to get the job right done. I do not know what I should do to laravel project to convert it into a WordPress working plugin and requests to its routes, laravel routes, being successfully work